# Rails Dynamic variable at link_to with JS

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, link-to

I have form to showing all list from some filter form with js and also another button that direct to another action on the same controller BUT still carry the value of the form filter.
For the js things had done properly, but for the the other button, I still confuse.

My BalanceTransactions controller:

```
def end_period
  #some coding
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.js
  end
end

def end_period_close
  year=params[:year]

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect to goal_path }
  end
end
```

My end_period.html.erb:

```
<%= form_tag end_period_balance_transactions_path, :method => "get", :id => "headers_search" do %>
  <td><%= select_year(Date.today, :prompt => 'Choose year') %></td>
  <td><%= submit_tag "Check", :name => nil, :class => "btn btn-info", :remote => true %></td>
  <td><%= link_to "Close", nil, :id => "close_button", :class => "btn btn-danger" %></td>
<% end %>

<%= render :partial => 'end_period_table' %>
```

When I click on [Check] button rails re-render the partial, and it done nicely work with the filter. And I still confuse on how I can deliver the [year] dynamicaly for the [Close] button.

I also done trying with the balance_transactions.js.coffe, which:
    $ ->
      $("#close_button").click ->
      year = $("#date_year").val()
      $.get("end_period_close", { year: year })

Sorry for the bad question and grammar, first post.

Thanks and regard,
Kristono Sugiarto

Comment: thanks @jvnill I don't know how to make it colorfull like that or I just don't read enough. Thanks anyway. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one

```
$ ->
  $('#close_button').click ->
    $.ajax
      url: 'your url here' # appending .erb to the filename gives you access to named routes
      data:
        year: $('#date_year').val()
```

Comment: It still redirect to the same page, and not redirect to goal_path there. Should I change that nil on close link_to to be something else?

Comment: sorry i thought you wanted to go to the same page since the url for link_to is nil.  to what url do you want to go?

Comment: actually it's no matter which url, but if it can, I need to go to root_url. I think coding at def end_period_close still not loaded yet.

Comment: if you need to go to a specific url, then just pass a url option to $.ajax like in my updated answer

Comment: It still didn't go to the url and the code inside the action still didn't touched. I try to put an error code, but it don't show any error sign.

Comment: I use jQuery function .attr to add the params to the link_to.
Thanks anyway for the helping @jvnill your answer make me understand more about coffescript :)

Comment: No sir, after some time try and think about it. Your solution was come to the best answer and work like charm..! Thanks, you save my day